# Unzip in Unix create Files with 000 permission

Tags: windows, unix, unzip

I have created a zip in Windows. Transferred it into Unix. Used the unzip command to unzip the zip. It results in the files getting created with no permission. Something like "---------- 1 root root   10930 Nov 23 07:54 a.txt"

This results in file permission issues. Is there any way i can unzip the zip to default umask value of the Operating system

Comment: Old fashioned ZIP archives do not store any file permissions at all. So the normal permissions masks _are_ applied when you unzip such a package. So most likely your current file permission masks were wrong...

Comment: If that is the case then the normal permission mask is 0027 when i do the umask. So in case you make the zip in Windows and then copy in unix and then do the unzip then 0027 should have been the default file permission which is not happening. Is there something which i have missed?

Comment: Not sure. How do you unzip the file and what account to you use? How do you login to that account? Note that there is no such thing as a "normal permission mask". That is up to the setup of the shell or the login shell of the current session.

Comment: Hi arkascha, Thank you for your reply. What i meant was the unzip is being done in unix via root user. Also what i mean  with the normal permissions masks mean when you run the command "umask" it returns with the value as 0027. My question is why after unzip the files created are having no permission at all

Comment: That is indeed strange. There must be some other factor involved. Maybe you extract the archive at a location in the file system that is mounted with special rules?

Comment: The `-X` option to `zip` will prevent it from storing file permissions, which might (or might not) resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks all for your inputs. What i came to know is unzip doesn't play much of a part in the file permissions. Whatever comes in us from the zip is unzipped in unix. The issue was related to Cygwin wherein the files when zipped comes with 000 permissions.

http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/vim-and-file-permissions-on-Windows-7-td61390.html

Answer (score 1):

What i came to know is unzip doesn't play much of a part in the file permissions. Whatever comes in us from the zip is unzipped in unix. The issue was related to Cygwin wherein the files when zipped comes with 000 permissions.  [cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/…](http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/vim-and-file-permissions-on-Windows-7-td61390.html)
                    – Anand Builders